# Open LinkedIn application (contact profile page) from my android app using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, linkedin-api

I try to open LinkedIn Android App (Profile screen) from my own app.

I found that it can be possible using:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("linkedin://profile/"+profileId));
```

where `profileId`, it's number like this: `190485666`

But I don't know profileId in necessary format, because when I send request to getting contact list:

`http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,public-profile-url,picture-url)`

I getting `profileId` in next format: `UVIQw3UQqZ`

How can I open profile screen of user from my LinkedIn contact list using Android intent?
**OR** How to get profileId in numeric format?